# Android TextView text overflow indicator?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the last three characters of a TextView with '...' but only if the current text overflows the TextView. I have to limit the TextView to 1 line but sometimes the text is too long and I would like to show '...' at the end to indicate the text is longer than what is showing.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize
to configure the display of the "...".

Comment: Doesn't this just make sure the word being cut off is not cut in the middle? How would I make it replace the last three characters with the '...'?

Comment: If you set max lines to 1 and set this to option END, I believe you will have what you are looking for. The alternative operation would be very cumbersome and based on font width/height and number of characters, basically forcing you to determine the likely length of laid out text and then calculate a cut off. I really think you should try to play around with this option and layout gravity to see if you can find a workable solution before you go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Also, you might have to use `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` on the `TextView` if you can't get the ellipses to show.

Comment: Ah thanks, I needed the android:scrollHorizontally="true" as well as the android:ellipsize="end". Works great, thanks for the help.

Comment: @NickCampion, please edit your answer and add the little bit of stuff that you wrote in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a common task called truncating. You would need to find the maximum characters you think will fit (-3 for the 3 periods) and then do something like this:

```
int MAX_CHARS = 55;  // for example
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
if(tv.getText().toString().length >= MAX_CHARS){
    tv.setText(tv.getText().toString().substring(0,MAX_CHARS) + "...");
}
```

Remember some characters are wider than others, depending on the font, so you might want to try all uppercase Os when trying to find out what your MAX_CHARS should be. (commonly one of the wider characters in my experience)

Comment: I would try @nick-campion 's way first, then if it's not working for you you could do something like the above.

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" will do it for you.

Comment: @romain-guy you should be prepping for your meetup tonight and not downvoting me ;)

Comment: @RomainGuy no it wont do it for me (sometimes it does, often not).